# Cannot find the data record in database table qtype_multichoice_options - Moodle

Tags: database, moodle

When accessing a question of a quiz, I receive the following message:

"Cannot find the data record in database table qtype_multichoice_options qtype_multichoice_options"

But I checked at database all the related data, and everything seems to be there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, these are the steps that can be done to solve the problem:
Edit the quiz. Open question by question until you find the one that has some kind of issue. 
Delete that question and open the quiz again, probably everything gonna works fine, otherwise, look for more questions with the same issue and delete them.
Maybe a question is messed up because some strange characters were included during importation or creation process.

Check for more detailed info: http://www.moodlenews.com/2014/how-to-fix-cannot-find-the-data-record-in-database-table-question_multichoice/